# ridiculous proc/meminfo in android. What does 'size' mean?

Tags: android, size, dalvik

I've been digging into memory usage in my app.

So, to know memory usage, I write some scripts that runs `meminfo` (each line shows after 10second)

```
NativeSize DalvikSize TotalSize
89556   5895    95451
89556   5959    95515
89556   6023    95579
89556   6087    95643
89556   6151    95707
89556   6215    95771
89556   6279    95835

NativeAlloc DalvikAlloc TotalAlloc
13943   3238    17181
15959   3334    19293
16264   3390    19654
16570   3447    20017
16877   3503    20380
17177   3559    20736
17251   3636    20887

NativeFree  DalvikFree  TotalFree
376 2657    3033
8   2625    2633
27  2633    2660
44  2640    2684
26  2648    2674
42  2656    2698
280 2643    2923
```

`NativeFree = NativeSize - NativeAlloc`, right?

And another question, `NativeSize` varys when my application loads other animation. I think `NativeSize` is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***(Pre Honeycomb):***

There are two heaps in adnroid. `Dalvik heap` and `native heap`. Your app data is stored in Dalvik heap except for bitmaps. For bitmaps, image meta data is stored in Dalvik heap, but actual bitmap pixel data is stored in native heap.

`NativeSize` is the amount of memory your app is using on `native heap`. For example, if you load more images you will see that `NativeSize` will grow. This is why NativeSize varies when your application loads other animation.

I guess `NativeFree`, `DalvikFree` are the bytes freed, so it has nothing to do with `NativeSize - NativeAlloc`.

See this for more info:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: in details of question, The program runs and load arbitrary something, nativeSize doesn`t vary, but I think nativeSize is determined when program starts. I think this video will be helpful for me. so good. thx.